# Memory leak in GTK under Windows 7 in gtk_widget_queue_draw

Tags: windows, gcc, memory-leaks, gtk, mingw

The following GTK program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
GtkVBox *vbox;
GtkWindow *win;
gboolean Timer (gpointer user_data)
{
   gtk_widget_queue_draw (GTK_WIDGET (vbox));
   return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
   win = (GtkWindow*)gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   vbox = (GtkVBox*)gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 1);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), GTK_WIDGET(vbox));
   g_timeout_add (200, Timer, 0);
   gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(win));
   gtk_main();
   return 0;
}
```

Leaks under Windows 7 64-bit when compiled using gcc 4.5.2 as the task manager shows. It does not leak when compiled under Windows XP 32-bit. The program does nothing. It creates a window, put there are box and then calls to gtk_widget_queue_draw from a timer each 200ms.

Here is a batch file to compile and link the test. The variable GTK is set to directory containing the binary distribution of GTK. E.g. 2.24.10 in this case.

```
set GTK=c:/temp/GTK
gcc -c -mms-bitfields -I%gtk%/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I%gtk%/lib/gdk-2.0/include -I%gtk%/lib/glib-2.0/include -I%gtk%/include -I%gtk%/include/atk-1.0 -I%gtk%/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I%gtk%/include/cairo -I%gtk%/include/pango-1.0 -I%gtk%/include/gio-win32-2.0 -I%gtk%/include/glib-2.0 -I%gtk%/include/gtk-2.0 test.c
gcc test.o --mwindows -Wl,-luuid -L%gtk%/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -o test.exe
```

Any thoughts? What is broken here GTK, gcc, MinGW? Some compiler/linker options missed?

Comment: Did you try running with a memory leak checker to see where the leaked memory was allocated?

Comment: I tested under Win XP and under Win 7 (both 32-bit) and I can confirm that there is no leakage.

Comment: It seems that this one: 
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2012-March/msg00009.html is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Windows 7 64-bit`, using `32-bit MinGW` and `GTK+`.

I have a similar case without the `gtk_widget_queue_draw (GTK_WIDGET (vbox));` call in the `Timer` function.

My impression is that it is the `g_timeout_add()` that induce the memory leak (as reported on the process tab in the windows task manager)
PTL.

Answer (score 1):

This was GTK [bug 685959](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685959). Most of the leak was fixed in GTK 2.24.14.

[Bug 707760](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707760) tracks the packages (binaries, bundle) update.

Comment: I have the same problem and this indeed seems to be the bug linked to the leak.

Comment: The biggest leak has been fixed since then. The fix is available since GTK 2.24.14.

Comment: True, but as I'm writing this there is no GTK+ 2.24.14 package for Windows yet. So you'll either have to compile from source yourself or downgrade to 2.24.0 as a temporary workaround (the big leak was introduced in 2.24.8).