# GTK+: leaks memory with gtk_label_set_text

Tags: windows, gtk

I have installed last all-in-one bundle GTK+ for windows 32 bit.

I have a problem with function `gtk_label_set_text`: it leaks memory when it is called recursively

There is an example code below. It leaks memory about 1Mb every 20 seconds

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean update_label(gpointer);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *label = NULL;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),label);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    g_timeout_add(10,(GtkFunction)update_label,label);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

gboolean update_label(gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *label = data;
    gchar tmpbuf[100];
    sprintf(tmpbuf , "Random text %i\n",rand());
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label),tmpbuf);

   return TRUE;
}
```

The code creates a windows with label and updates it every 10 ms.
Can someone help me? Is there something wrong in GTK+ library or in my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a duplicate [Memory leak in GTK under Windows 7 in gtk_widget_queue_draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837776/memory-leak-in-gtk-under-windows-7-in-gtk-widget-queue-draw). What is the version of GTK you use ?

Comment: 2.24.10, 
I have tried to read bug 685959, but it's not simple for me.
I understand that they work around and it should be solved in 2.24.14 version, but I don't understand how to bypass it with  current version.
My GtkLabel is a timer and I have to update it every 100 ms.
do you have any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Either you upgrade to 2.24.14, or you rebuild GTK with the [patch](https://bug685959.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=227018) stated as committed for that bug.