# Addressing memory leak in GTK+ / Queue with windows

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, message-queue

I was trying a GTK application in windows and just now started to learn GTK.

GTK Version:

```
gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32
```

Application requirement:

```
1.  Multi threaded
2.  Queue based communication
3.  GTK window to update a image data in screen with 5 secs delay
```

Application functionality :

```
1.  2 thread (producer and other consumer)
    Producer will post a string to queue manager which will form a structure and post the data to the respective queue
2.  Upon posting the data to the queue manager producer thread shall update the respective image on the screen
3.  Consumer will be monitoring the queue and on receiving data consumer will process the data according

The application is running as expected:
```

**The issue i am facing here is the memory (according to windows resource monitor )**

```
Confused which one is causing the LEAK -- GTK or my queue or ???

    the program starts with 26K memory and on certain time it reaches 190000K memory. So i see memory leak
    request some guidance in handling this issue
```

this is the sample program flow which i am working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define sleep(n) g_usleep(1000 * n)

G_LOCK_DEFINE_STATIC (queue_memchunk);
static GMemChunk   *queue_memchunk = NULL;
static GTrashStack *free_queue_nodes = NULL;
GQueue* msgQueueId[7];


#define NORMAL_TEXT     0
#define WARNING_TEXT    1
#define STATUS_TEXT     2
#define NORMAL_FONT     0
#define SMALL_FONT      1
#define NORM_FONT_UNLTD 2
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE        5120
#define TRACK_ONE_SIZE      150
#define TRACK_TWO_SIZE      100
#define TRACK_THREE_SIZE    100
#define FSM_CHANNEL     1



typedef struct
{
    int msgType;
    int msgSize;
    char msgBuf[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
}STRUCT_MSG;

GtkWidget* window;

struct WidgetsAlive
{
    GtkWidget* widPtr;
    int widIndex;
    struct WidgetsAlive* dependants;
    struct WidgetsAlive* next;
};

/* Linked list ptr to the widgets alive */
static struct WidgetsAlive* wAlive = NULL;
static struct WidgetsAlive* depFirstNode = NULL;
typedef struct {
    char* fileName;
    }dispTextPage_struct;

    typedef struct {
        char* data;
         int row;
         int column;
        char textType;
        char fontType;
        }updateTextPage_struct;

int waitForLoop;

void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[]);
void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration);
gboolean dispTextPage_callBack(dispTextPage_struct *params);
int dispTextPage(char* fileName, int duration);


int destroyNotify(void){
    printf("Notfiy called in");
    while (gtk_events_pending())
          {
            g_usleep (1);
            gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);
          }
    waitForLoop = 0;
    return 0;

}


gpointer main_callback(gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Initializing the display library\n");
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_widget_realize( window );
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    g_thread_create(main_callback, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
}

void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration)
{
    int index;
    gdk_threads_enter();
    destroyWidget(0);
    GtkWidget *image;
    image = gtk_image_new_from_file(fileName);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
    gtk_widget_show(image);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gdk_threads_leave();
}

struct WidgetsAlive* getWidgetFromList(int widgetIndex)
{
        struct WidgetsAlive *temp, *prev;
        temp = wAlive;
        prev = NULL;
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
                /* Widget list is empty. Nothing to destroy */
                return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp != NULL)
            {
                if(temp->widIndex == widgetIndex)
                {
                        return temp;
                }
                else
                {
                        //printf("Iterating to the next widget in the list, since the index is different\n");
                        prev = temp;
                        temp = temp->next;
                }
             }
        //printf("No widget with index %d found to destroy, Please check the index..\n", index);
        }
    return NULL;
}

int destroyWidget(int index)
{
    GList *children, *iter;
        struct WidgetsAlive *temp, *prev, *next, *depTemp;
        temp = wAlive;
        prev = wAlive;
        gtk_window_resize((GtkWindow*)window, 800, 600);
        children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(window));
        for(iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter)){
            gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
            //printf("Deleting Widget\n");
        }
        g_list_free(iter);
        g_list_free(children);

    gtk_window_resize((GtkWindow*)window, 800, 600);
  /*  if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (temp->widIndex == index)
        {
            if (temp->widPtr != NULL)
            {
                if (GTK_IS_WIDGET(temp->widPtr))
                {
                    //gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget*)temp->widPtr);
                    printf("Destroying widget Done\n");
                }
            }
            depTemp = depFirstNode;
            next = depFirstNode;
            while (depTemp != NULL)
            {
                depTemp = depTemp->next;
                free(next);
                next = NULL;
                next = depTemp;
            }
            depFirstNode = NULL;
            wAlive = NULL;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp != NULL)
            {
                if(temp->widIndex == index)
                {
                    printf("Found widget match\n");
                    if (temp->widPtr != NULL)
                    {
                        if (GTK_IS_WIDGET(temp->widPtr))
                        {
                            //gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget*)temp->widPtr);
                        }
                    }
                    prev->next = temp->next;
                    free(temp);
                    temp = NULL;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }*/
}


int addToWidgetsAlive(GtkWidget* inWidget, struct WidgetsAlive* dependants)

{
    /*struct WidgetsAlive *temp, *node;
    node = (struct WidgetsAlive*)malloc(sizeof(struct WidgetsAlive));
    node->widPtr = inWidget;
    node->widIndex = 1;
    if (dependants != NULL)
        node->dependants = dependants;
    else
        node->dependants = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    if (wAlive == NULL)
    {
        wAlive = node;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = wAlive;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        node->widIndex = temp->widIndex + 1;
        temp->next = node;
    }
    return node->widIndex;*/
    return 0;
}

int dispTextPage(char* fileName, int duration)
{
//dispTextPage_struct *params;
    dispTextPage_struct *params;
    params = (dispTextPage_struct*)malloc(sizeof(dispTextPage_struct));
    params->fileName = fileName;
    /*
    memset(&params2,'\0',sizeof(dispTextPage_struct));
    params2.fileName = fileName;*/
    while(gtk_events_pending()){
        gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);
        g_usleep(1000);
    }
    printf("Gidel added \n");
    waitForLoop=1;
    g_idle_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,dispTextPage_callBack,params,destroyNotify);
    while(waitForLoop == 1){
        g_usleep(1000);
    }
    free(params);
}


gboolean dispTextPage_callBack(dispTextPage_struct *params)
{
    char* fileName = params -> fileName;
    int index;
    int isJustifyCenter = 0;

    GtkWidget *textv;
    GdkWindow *textv_window;
    GdkPixmap *pixmap;
    GtkTextBuffer* textBuffer;
    GdkColor color;
    printf("\ntextpage :,1\n");
    destroyWidget(0);
    textv = gtk_text_view_new ();
    gtk_text_view_set_left_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 22);
    gtk_text_view_set_right_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 20);
    gtk_text_view_set_pixels_above_lines(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv),1);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_WRAP_CHAR);
    if (isJustifyCenter == 1)
    {
        gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    }

    gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);
    gtk_text_view_set_cursor_visible(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), textv);
    printf("\ntextpage :,3\n");
    textv_window = gtk_text_view_get_window (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (textv),GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_TEXT);
    gdk_color_parse ("#68604d", &color);
    pixmap = gdk_pixmap_create_from_xpm ((GdkDrawable *) textv_window, NULL,&color, fileName);
    printf(" textpage :,4\n");
    gdk_window_set_back_pixmap (textv_window, pixmap, FALSE);
    g_object_unref(pixmap);
    textBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv));
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "bold","foreground", "Black", NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "Redbold","foreground", "Red",NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "fontSize","font", "saxmono 20",NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "smallFontSize", "font", "saxmono 14", NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "fontweight","weight", 1000,NULL);
    index = addToWidgetsAlive(textv, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(textv);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
//free(params);
return 0;
}
gboolean updateTextPage_callBack(updateTextPage_struct *params)
{
    char* data = params -> data;
    int row = params -> row;
    int column = params -> column;
    char textType = params -> textType;
    char fontType = params -> fontType;
    int i;
    int j;
    struct WidgetsAlive* textWindowWidget = NULL;
    GtkWidget *tempTextWidgetPtr;
    GtkTextBuffer *textBuffer;
    gchar* tempLineStr;
    char temp[512];

    GtkTextIter endIter;
    GtkTextIter startIter;
    if(fontType == NORMAL_FONT)
    {
        if(row >15 || row < 0)
            row =15;
        if(column >31 || column < 0)
            column =0;
    }
    // If there is no valid string to write, return
    if ((data == NULL) || (strlen(data) == 0)){
        free(params);
        return FALSE;
    }
    textWindowWidget = getWidgetFromList(1);
    if (textWindowWidget != NULL)
    {
        tempTextWidgetPtr = textWindowWidget->widPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Error */
        free(params);
        return FALSE;
    }
    textBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tempTextWidgetPtr));
    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (textBuffer, &endIter);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (textBuffer, &startIter);
    i = gtk_text_buffer_get_line_count(textBuffer);
    memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
    if (i < (row+1))
    {
        for (j = i; j < (row + 1); j++)
        {
            strcat(temp, "\n");
        }
        //Move one char forward if you are at the newline char
        while ((gtk_text_iter_get_char(&endIter) != 0))
        {
            gtk_text_iter_forward_char(&endIter);
        }
        gtk_text_buffer_insert(textBuffer,&endIter, temp, -1);
        gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (textBuffer, &endIter);
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(textBuffer, &endIter, row);
        memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
        for (j = 0; j < column+1; j++)
        {
            strcat(temp, " ");
        }
        gtk_text_buffer_insert(textBuffer, &endIter, temp, -1);
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(textBuffer, &startIter, row);
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(textBuffer, &endIter, row);
        gtk_text_view_forward_display_line_end(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tempTextWidgetPtr), &endIter);
        tempLineStr = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(textBuffer, &startIter, &endIter, FALSE);
        memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
        i = strlen(tempLineStr);
        if (column > i)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (column - i); j++)
            {
                strcat(temp, " ");
            }
            gtk_text_buffer_insert(textBuffer,&endIter, temp, -1);
        }
    }
    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line_offset(textBuffer, &startIter, row, column);
    endIter = startIter;
    i = strlen(data);
    j = 0;
    while (j < i)
    {
        if ((gtk_text_iter_get_char(&endIter) == '\n'))
        {
            gtk_text_iter_backward_char(&endIter);
            break;
        }
        gtk_text_iter_forward_char(&endIter);
        j++;
    }
    if (gtk_text_iter_compare(&endIter, &startIter) == 1) // delete only if enditer is greater than startiter
        gtk_text_buffer_delete( textBuffer, &startIter, &endIter);
    memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
    j = strlen(data);
    if ( ((j + column) > 32) && (fontType == NORMAL_FONT))
    {
        strncpy(temp, data, (32 - column));
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(temp, data, j);
    }
    gtk_text_buffer_insert(textBuffer,&startIter, temp, -1);

    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (textBuffer, &endIter);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (textBuffer, &startIter);
    if(textType==NORMAL_TEXT)
        gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name (textBuffer, "bold", &startIter, &endIter);
    else
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line_offset(textBuffer, &startIter, row, column);
        gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name (textBuffer, "Redbold", &startIter, &endIter);
    }
    if((fontType == NORMAL_FONT) || (fontType == NORM_FONT_UNLTD))
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name (textBuffer, "fontSize", &startIter, &endIter);
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line_offset(textBuffer, &startIter, row, column);
        gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name (textBuffer, "smallFontSize", &startIter, &endIter);
    }
    gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name (textBuffer, "fontweight", &startIter, &endIter);
    gtk_widget_show(tempTextWidgetPtr);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    free(params);
    return FALSE;
}


void updateTextPage(char* data, int row, int column,char textType,char fontType)
{
    updateTextPage_struct *params;
    params = (updateTextPage_struct*)malloc(sizeof(updateTextPage_struct));
    params->data = data;
    params->row = row;
    params->column = column;
    params->textType = textType;
    params->fontType = fontType;
    while(gtk_events_pending())
    {
        usleep(1000);
    }
    waitForLoop=1;
    g_idle_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,updateTextPage_callBack,params,destroyNotify);
    while(waitForLoop == 1){
        usleep(1000);
    }
}

void *fsmThread_RunFunction1()
    {

    int atmMsgRetVal;
    static STRUCT_MSG atmRxMsg;
    while(1)
    {
        memset(&atmRxMsg,'\0',sizeof(STRUCT_MSG));
        atmMsgRetVal = PendMessageQ(FSM_CHANNEL,&atmRxMsg);
        if(atmMsgRetVal == 0)
        {

            if(ProcessfsmMessage(atmRxMsg.msgType, (char *)atmRxMsg.msgBuf))
                continue;
        }
        else{
            //sleep(1);
            usleep(10*1000);
        }
    }
    }

int ProcessfsmMessage(int msgType, char *msgBuf)
{
    printf("fsmThread_RunFunction data recieved %s\n",msgBuf);



}

void *fsmThread_RunFunction()
{
    int pollMsgRetVal = -1;
    sleep(5000);
    dispTextPage("icon132.gif",0);
    char data[500] = "FSM POST MESSAGE\n";
    while(1){

        printf("Now Entry for fsmThread_RunFunction\n");
        PostMessageQ(FSM_CHANNEL,1, data,strlen(data));
        dispTextPage("icon165.gif",0);
        sleep(500);
        printf("Now Exit for fsmThread_RunFunction\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GThread *fsmThreadId,*fsmThreadId1;
    GError *error = NULL;
    g_thread_init(NULL);
    //dispInit(argc, argv);

   // sleep(5000);
    CreateMessageQ(FSM_CHANNEL);
    printf("Initializing the display library\n");
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_widget_realize( window );
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);


    dispInfoPage("icon165.gif",1);
    sleep(5000);
    printf("Now create ethread ");
    fsmThreadId = g_thread_create(fsmThread_RunFunction,NULL,TRUE,&error);
    if (error) {
      fflush(stderr);
      exit(1);
    }
    fsmThreadId1 = g_thread_create(fsmThread_RunFunction1,NULL,TRUE,&error);
    if (error) {
      fflush(stderr);
      exit(1);
    }

    gtk_main();

    g_thread_join(fsmThreadId);
    sleep(2);

    printf("ENd of main");
    return 0;
}


int PostMessageQ(int channel, int msgType, char *msgBuf, int msgSize)
{
    STRUCT_MSG txMsg;
    memset(&txMsg,'\0',sizeof(STRUCT_MSG));
    txMsg.msgType = msgType;
    txMsg.msgSize = msgSize;
    memcpy(&txMsg.msgBuf[0],&msgBuf[0],msgSize);
    g_queue_push_head (msgQueueId[channel], (char *)&txMsg);
    return 0;
}

int PendMessageQ(int channel,STRUCT_MSG* rxMsgptr)
{
    if (g_queue_is_empty(msgQueueId[channel])){
        return 1;
    }
    STRUCT_MSG* rxMsg = (STRUCT_MSG*) malloc(sizeof(STRUCT_MSG));
    rxMsg = ( STRUCT_MSG*) g_queue_pop_tail (msgQueueId[channel]);
    rxMsgptr->msgType = rxMsg->msgType;
    rxMsgptr->msgSize = rxMsg->msgSize;
    memcpy(&rxMsgptr->msgBuf[0],&rxMsg->msgBuf[0],sizeof(rxMsg->msgBuf));
    free(rxMsg);
    return 0;
}


void CreateMessageQ (int channel)
{
  G_LOCK (queue_memchunk);
  msgQueueId[channel] = g_trash_stack_pop (&free_queue_nodes);

  if (!msgQueueId[channel])
    {
      if (!queue_memchunk)
        queue_memchunk = g_mem_chunk_new ("GLib GQueue chunk",
                                          sizeof (GNode),
                                          sizeof (GNode) * 128,
                                          G_ALLOC_ONLY);
      msgQueueId[channel] = g_chunk_new (GQueue, queue_memchunk);
    }
  G_UNLOCK (queue_memchunk);

  msgQueueId[channel]->head = NULL;
  msgQueueId[channel]->tail = NULL;
  msgQueueId[channel]->length = 0;
}
```

Comment: GTk3 (at least on Linux) is using some significant memory for one-time resources (likes fonts, bitmaps, images...) required at startup. If memory stays at 180Mbytes, I would not panic; if it continues growing, be concerned. And use a memory leak detector (like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Linux), also compile with all warnings -e.g `gcc -Wall -g`. BTW, Linux might be a better platform for GTK development than Windows (you could start developping on Linux, and port to Windows when your software has matured).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :: the code which i have been working is from one our existing linux application with 5 years of age.

Comment: Then improve it on Linux (for GTK3), use `valgrind` to check about memory leaks, and later port it to Windows.

Comment: Doing some diagnostic without knowing which version of GTK you're using is pretty much pointless: it's pretty much reading in a crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us the version of GTK you're using, but chances are this is a known problem of some older GTK 2 releases. Check my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950519/518853

Subscribe to [bug 707760](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707760) to track bundles update.

Comment: gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.If this version has issues what is best version that you would recommend in GTK2 base

Comment: The same as stated in the comments of the answer I pointed to: downgrade to 2.24.0 ([download 2.24.x bundles](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/)), or build latest 2.24.x >= 2.24.14 yourself.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me out find one of the leak in the program other than this leak i also had leak in my queue mechanism and program error. 1. Unwanted GQUEUE create used - g_QUEUE_NEW() 2. and in pend data 2. Missed a free. If you can point some would be helpful.Posted the same as answer.

Comment: can you please give some pointers on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590410/gtk-system-takes-longer-time-in-displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

1. Unwanted GQUEUE create used so changed CreateMessageQ as below:

   void CreateMessageQ (int channel)
     {
     msgQueueId[channel] = g_queue_new();
     }
2. Changes in PendMessageQ free was the issue:

   int PendMessageQ(int channel,STRUCT_MSG* rxMsgptr)
   {
   while (g_queue_is_empty(msgQueueId[channel])){
       g_usleep(10*1000);
   }
   char *data = ( data*) g_queue_pop_tail (msgQueueId[channel]);
   memcpy(&rxMsgptr->msgBuf[0],&data[0],sizeof(data));
   free(data);
   return 0;
   }