# Python WebkitGTK memory leak(clear function)

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I have a backbone 1 page application that need to run for hours moving along different routes. I have created the simple script on python that runs my browser and on full screen.

```
import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, WebKit

class BrowserWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()

        self.webview.connect("load-finished", self._load_finish)
        self.webview.connect("navigation-requested", self._navigation_requested)

        settings = self.webview.get_settings()
        print settings.get_property("enable-page-cache")
        settings.set_property("enable-page-cache", False)
        self.webview.set_settings(settings)
        self.webview.load_uri("http://www.google.com/")
        self.add(self.webview)
        self.show_all()

    def _load_finish(self, view, frame):
        print "Loading completed"
        print view

    def _navigation_requested(self, view, frame, request):
        print "Mavigation change requested"
        self.webview.get_back_forward_list().clear()
        return False

def main():
    Gtk.init(sys.argv)

    window = BrowserWindow()
    window.show()
    window.fullscreen()

    Gtk.main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem here is everytime it changes the routes, it increases the memory by some amount. Those with more images increases the memory more quickly. And instead of using anything that in memory, it tends to use more memory but not utilize it.

I tried searching for a clear function, but didn't get any help with it. I also tried QTWebkit which had clear function, but it didn't helped either.

Comment: What **specific** versions of webkit have you tried? There have always been problems with memory usage, but some of them have been fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: Also note that GTK on MS Windows had a memory leak on every widget redraw (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837776/memory-leak-in-gtk-under-windows-7-in-gtk-widget-queue-draw) and [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685959)). The current windows build of PyGTK has **not** been updated with the fix. If you are on windows, the only way to avoid that memory leak is to build PyGTK from source using the latest version of GTK. That said, there may also be issues with webkit as ekhumoro points out.

Comment: I am using PyQT4 and/or PyWebkitGTK. I am on Debian/XFCE4 with a limited amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: are you sure the memory use is an actual problem? Modern browsers (and webviews) can have very complex caching behaviour: *"tends to use more memory but not utilize it"* could very well be a overly simplified picture of the situation.

That said WebkitGTK does let you have some control over the caching behaviour: take a look at `set_cache_model()` and related functions (these are part of WebKitWebContext in webkit2gtk and global functions in webkitgtk).

Comment: I am trying to find that on : http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/
Can you me more specific with the URL with the WebKitWebContext?
The memory grows so high around >40% and it tends to slow down the behavior of the page.